# Виртуальный джойстик срабатывает при нажатии на кнопки UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Делаю джойстик. Если использовать только джойстик или только кнопки на экране, то все нормально. Если при зажатом джойстике нажать кнопку, то он сдвинется в её сторону. Повторюсь, по отдельности все нормально. 
Код джойстика:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!player) {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
    }

    if (enabeled)
    {
        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        dir = pos - transform.position;
        marker.transform.position =transform.position+Vector3.ClampMagnitude(dir,250);
        if(dir.magnitude>5)
        { player.speed = dir.normalized; }
    }
    else {
        marker.transform.position = transform.position;
        player.speed = Vector2.zero;
    }
}public  void OnDrag (PointerEventData pointerEventData){
    Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
    dir = pos - transform.position;
    if (dir.magnitude < 350)
    {
        enabeled = true;
    }
}
public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
{
    enabeled = false;
}
```

Comment: Кнопки реализованы, через  события OnClick

Comment: Просто скачайте ассет с джойстиком из ассет стора и посмотрите как там все работает

Answer (score 0):

добавь булево значение, к примеру JoystickIsUse и при нажатии на джойстик делай его true, а также добавь проверку к кнопкам управления, если JoystickIsUse == false, то считывать клавиши, если оно == true, то не считывать, также можно переводить движение джойстика на оси horizontal и vertical
для того, чтобы считывать движение джойстика можно использовать Vector3.Angle
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html

public Transform Stick

```
Vector3 StickDirX = Stick.position - transform.position.x;
float angleX = Vector3.Angle(StickDirX, transform.forward);
Vector3 StickDirX = Stick.position - transform.position.y;
float angleY = Vector3.Angle(StickDirY, transform.forward);
```

// назавем код JoystickControl

```
    public float Vertical()
        {
            return ((angleX + Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        }
        else return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    public float Horizontal()
        {
            return ((angleY + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        }
        else return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
```

После чего в движении используй не Inpu.GetAxis(вертикаль) и горизонталь, а используй флоат получаемый в коде выше,(public float Vertical() и public float Horizontal())
Вот пример движения игрока с такими значениями:

```
public JoystickControl JC; // подключаем скрипт JoystickControl в этот скрипт
public Transform Player
public float Speed;
public void Start()
{
Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}
 private void Move()
    {
        MoveV3 = Vector3.zero;
        MoveV3.x = JC.Horizontal() * Speed;
        MoveV3.z = JC.Vertical() * Speed;
        Player.position += MoveV3;
    }
public void Update()
{
    Move();
}
```

Скрипт, который показан выше - считывает положение стика на джойстике и его разницу 
Если что-то не работает(тестил, у меня работает) или возникли какие-то трудности, напиши сюда https://vk.com/club185855760 (Не реклама) в этой группе я тебе помогу написать скрипт полностью и помочь разобраться с ним.